# Validate a date in the future using simple branching

Tags: java

My problem when I try running this program is that everything compiles but when I run it it doesnt spit the correct results.

For example, I want to run the date 14/12/2017 and it says its a valid day

Can anyone help me catch the mistake, or is one of the "if" located or written wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FutureDate {
public static void main (String args[]){

  int inputMonth;
  int inputDate;
  int inputYear;
  final int currentMonth = 10;
  final int currentDate = 24;
  final int currentYear = 2013;
  final int numberOfDays = 31; 

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a month in format - mm: ");
  inputMonth = keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter a day in format - dd: ");
  inputDate= keyboard.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter a year in format - yyyy: ");
  inputYear = keyboard.nextInt();


  if (inputYear > currentYear && inputMonth > currentMonth && inputDate > currentDate)
  System.out.println("Valid year");

  if (inputMonth >= 1 && inputMonth <=12)
  System.out.println("Valid Month");

  if (inputMonth == 4 || inputMonth == 6 || inputMonth == 9 || inputMonth == 11 && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 30)
  System.out.println("Valid");

  if (inputMonth == 2 && inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 28)
  System.out.println("Valid Day");

  if (inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <= 31)
  System.out.println("Valid Day");

  if (inputYear < currentYear)  
  System.out.println ("Invalid year");

  if (inputDate < currentDate && inputMonth < currentMonth)
  System.out.println ("Invalid day");

  }
}
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Make up your mind please …

Comment: You have tagged this JavaScript, I think you meant to tag it Java? BTW, there are 29 days in February from time to time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this note: Only accept days 1-28 for February

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Note that we really recommend [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for dealing with date/time in Java.  Note that this would make the month/day validation really easy with the built-in types.

Answer (score 0):

Your fourth IF statement

```
if(inputDate >= 1 && inputDate <=31) System.out.println("Valid Day");
```

Will print the output.

You're not using else's, or otherwise separating your code into blocks, which means each of the IF statements is being evaluated by itself, regardless of the results of previous if statements.

After an IF statement, if you don't specify that the rest of the code should only be executed on success (using a block separated by {}) only the next statement will be conditional on the result. (In these cases, the System.out calls.)

Another small point.  You should probably take a look at your first IF statement.  Remember that when you look at that, all three of the conditions must be met for the statement to be evaluated as true.  Jan 14th 2014 is a "valid year" but that statement will evaluate as false.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a "valid date", you need to use nested if statements like this:

```
if (inputYear >= currentYear) {
    if (inputMonth >= currentMonth) {
        if (inputDate > currentDate) {
            System.out.println("Valid Date");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid day");
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Month");
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Year");
}
```

Input date `12 - 21 - 2013`

1) Check year - valid - go to next if statement (if not valid, print "invalid Year")

2) Check month - valid - do to next if statement (if not valid, print "invalid month")

3) check day - valid - print "valid day" (if not valid, print "invalid day")